# Docker setup for Nodejs React NextJS project local development

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I want to setup local work enviornment for a React NextJS application using Docker ubuntu 20.04 PC. So that I can run the docker image and connect a git repo path to run any node application. Dont want to install node and npm in pc. Everything will be manage from docker image. But project repo will be seperate from docker and mounted in docker.

Here is my files -

**Dockerfile**

```
#base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update apt
RUN apt-get update


# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get -y install vim && \
    apt-get -y install telnet && \
    apt-get -y install apt-utils && \
    apt-get -y install iputils-ping && \
    apt-get -y install zip unzip

# Install GIT and ca-certificates for SSL
RUN apt-get -y install wget ca-certificates && apt-get -y install git && apt-get -y install curl

# install apache 2
RUN apt-get -y install apache2
RUN apt-get update


# install Node and NPM
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.13.0
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

WORKDIR /tmp

# add api.bms apache config
COPY ./dev.local.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
RUN a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2ensite dev.local.conf

# Enable modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod proxy
RUN a2enmod proxy_http

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./cmd.sh /tmp
RUN chmod +x /tmp/cmd.sh

# run server
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/cmd.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nodejs_core:
    container_name: ${HOSTNAME}
    build:
      context: ${BUILD_CONTEXT}
      dockerfile: ${DOCKER_FILE}
    image: ${HOSTNAME}:latest
    hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
    volumes:
      - ${REPO_PATH}:${VOLUME_MOUNT}
    working_dir: ${VOLUME_MOUNT}
    ports:
      - ${PORT_MAPPING}
    environment:
      TZ: "Asia/Kolkata"
    command: ${START_UP_COMMAND}
    tty: false
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - docker_node

networks:
  docker_node:
    name: docker_node
    ipam:
        config:
            - subnet: 192.168.50.201/7
```

**dev.local.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

**cmd.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start Apache"
service apache2 start
service apache2 reload

cd /var/www/html
npm run dev

echo "Tail the server log"
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

**.env**

```
BUILD_CONTEXT=./
DOCKER_FILE=./Dockerfile

HOSTNAME=nodejs_core

# Only REPO_PATH will be change as per the project location
REPO_PATH=/var/www/html/dev.local
VOLUME_MOUNT=/var/www/html

PORT_MAPPING=3000:80
START_UP_COMMAND="bash /tmp/cmd.sh"
```

But application is not working and unable to run the next js project in my local pc. Can you please help.

Comment: The easiest way to get a local Node setup on Ubuntu is to just `apt-get install nodejs`, and you're essentially done; you can delete more or less everything else you have in the question.  Is there a specific reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: or at least use a offical node image. For development you dont need apache. If you use vscode, there is devcontainer https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your comment. I dont want to install nodejs in local pc. Instead create a docker setup such that it could run independently the node application.

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what does happen?  The setup you show here is incredibly complex and has a lot of parts that seem unnecessary; can you reduce it to a [mcve]?